# ASP.NET MVC project for management Membership , Role and Profile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, asp.net-roles

every body knows working with Membership , Roles and Profiles are common in most of ASP.NET project.

I am looking for  a simple project to do this activity with UI for end users. like "add user" , "add role" , "assign user to roles" and so on.

It's better be solution in MVC[3].

any idea?

Comment: Do you want a ready to use MVC project for a complete user management?

Comment: Yse, but management the default membership manager in asp.net.

Comment: I want a simple project that have pages for doing something, like assign a user to role or create a user form and so on

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post by Brady Gaster a while ago which may well suit your needs - implements a custom membership provider in ASP.NET MVC 3.

http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0

Answer (score 1):

here is another good one:
[SecurityGuard](http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/tools/kahanu/securityguard-nuget-package-for-asp-net-membership)

SecurityGuard is a complete ASP.NET MVC 3 and now MVC 4 beta application installable via NuGet.  If you need a complete way to manage your ASP.NET Membership system for your MVC application, this is the NuGet package to use.